# how to get the microphone streamed directly to the watson speechToText service

Tags: ibm-watson, speech-to-text

We'd like to pipe microphone directly to waton speech to text service , but it seems that we have to go through .wav first ? please take a look at the following codes, In particular I was trying to get the microphone streamed directly to the speechToText service. I believe this is the most common way of using mic, not piping it into a .wav and then stream the .wav file to stt:

```
var mic;
 var SpeechToTextV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/speech-to-text/v1');
 var fs = require('fs');
 var watson = require('watson-developer-cloud');
 var cp = require('child_process');
  mic = cp.spawn('arecord', ['--device=plughw:1,0', '--format=S16_LE', '--rate=44100', '--channels=1']); //, '--duration=10'
  mic.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
  stt();

  function stt() {
     console.log("openCMDS");
         var speech_to_text = new SpeechToTextV1({
         username: '',
         password: ''
         });
     var params = {
     content_type: 'audio/wav',
     model: 'zh-CN_BroadbandModel',
     continuous: true,
     inactivity_timeout: -1
     };
     recognizeStream = speech_to_text.createRecognizeStream(params);
         mic.stdout.pipe(recognizeStream);
         //mic.stdout.pipe(require('fs').createWriteStream('test.wav')); 

         // Pipe in the audio.
         fs.createReadStream('test.wav').pipe(recognizeStream);
         recognizeStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('transcription.txt'));
     recognizeStream.setEncoding('utf8'); 
     console.log("start record");
        recognizeStream.on('data', function(event) { onEvent('Data:', event); });
        recognizeStream.on('error', function(event) { onEvent('Error:', event); });
        recognizeStream.on('close', function(event) { onEvent('Close:', event); });
 // Display events on the console.
 function onEvent(name, event) {
     console.log(name, JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
      }

 }
```

Comment: the official speech to text api also mentioned this:  https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/speech-to-text/api/v1/node.html?node#websocket_methods

   // Pipe in the audio.
   fs.createReadStream('audio- 
   file.flac').pipe(recognizeStream);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Speech to Text service needs to know the format of the audio you are trying to send. 99% of the issues I've seen are because the service is expecting a different audio format than the one users are using.

```
'--format=S16_LE', '--rate=44100', '--channels=1'
```

That looks like a 44.1kHz PCM format.

In your code you are specifying:

```
content_type: 'audio/wav'
```

Take a look at the [supported audio formats](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/speech-to-text/audio-formats.html#audio-formats).

Maybe try with `audio/l16; rate=44100;`. You can also record the audio in a different format.

Finally, take a look at the [javascript-speech-sdk](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-javascript-sdk). We have examples of how to stream the microphone from the browser.

### Update

```
const mic = require('mic');
const SpeechToTextV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/speech-to-text/v1');
const speechToText = new SpeechToTextV1({
  username: 'YOUR USERNAME',
  password: 'YOUR PASSWORD',
  url: 'YOUR SERVICE URL',
  version: 'v1'
});

// 1. Microphone settings
const micInstance = mic({
  rate: 44100,
  channels: 2,
  debug: false,
  exitOnSilence: 6
});



// 2. Service recognize settings
const recognizeStream = speechToText.createRecognizeStream({
  content_type: 'audio/l16; rate=44100; channels=2',
  model: 'zh-CN_BroadbandModel',
  interim_results: true,
})

// 3. Start recording
const micInputStream = micInstance.getAudioStream();
micInstance.start();

console.log('Watson is listening, you may speak now.');

// 4. Pipe audio to service
const textStream = micInputStream.pipe(recognizeStream).setEncoding('utf8');

textStream.on('data', user_speech_text => console.log('Watson hears:', user_speech_text));
textStream.on('error', e => console.log(`error: ${e}`));
textStream.on('close', e => console.log(`close: ${e}`));
```

Comment: I did record my sound from microphone with the following code:  
  
  mic.stdout.pipe(require('fs').createWriteStream('test.wav')) ;   audio/l16 did not help , I'd like to know how to modify my code to stream microphone to stt service directly

Comment: WAVE format is not meant to be used for streaming, but for file based recognition, the header of the .wav file has the audio length in it. What you need to do is to capture the audio from the microphone and feed it to stt one chunk at a time, all within the same recognition session, use websockets for this. There is plenty of sample code in watson-developer-cloud

Comment: @Daniel Bolanos , Thanks for your prompt update, Could update my code to utilize websockets when you get a chance ?

Comment: I have modified my codes with "websockets" : var recognizeStream = mic.stdout.pipe(speech_to_text.createRecognizeStream(params)).setEncoding('utf8'); unfortunately I did not see any word on my screen , please take a look at my code on line 25:  https://gist.github.com/vkjuju/8349102e08563f384417ed2f129769c1

Comment: @JoeYang the problem here is clearly how you record and send the audio to the Speech to Text service. The "audio formats" link from my answer describes what are supposed audio formats. Instead of executing a command with `cp.spawn` try to find a library to help you record the audio in a supported format by the service. Take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/mic there are examples in the GitHub repo.

Comment: You can find a lot of sample code in github https://github.com/search?q=require%28%27mic%27%29+watson&type=Code

Comment: @German, Thanks for your update , so the difference is using the following code instead of cp.spawn?   var micInstance = mic({
    rate: '16000',
    channels: '1',
    debug: true,
    exitOnSilence: 6
});

Comment: @German,I just copied and pasted your codes to my raspberry pi ,it worked like a charm, the only difference is changing channel from 2 to 1, Thanks... will modify my original codes based on yours, hopefully I can make it work today...