# Speech to Text: Piping microphone stream to Watson STT with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I am currently trying to send a microphone stream to Watson STT service but for some reason, the Watson service is not receiving the stream (I'm guessing) so I get the error "Error: No speech detected for 30s".

Note that I have streamed a .wav file to Watson and I have also tested piping micInputStream to my local files so I know both are at least set up correctly. I am fairly new to NodeJS / javascript so I'm hoping the error might be obvious.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const mic = require('mic');
var SpeechToTextV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/speech-to-text/v1');

var speechToText = new SpeechToTextV1({
  iam_apikey: '{key_here}',
  url: 'https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api'
});

var params = {
  content_type: 'audio/l16; rate=44100; channels=2',
  interim_results: true
};

const micParams = { 
    rate: 44100, 
    channels: 2, 
    debug: false, 
    exitOnSilence: 6
  }
  const micInstance = mic(micParams);
  const micInputStream = micInstance.getAudioStream();

  micInstance.start();
  console.log('Watson is listening, you may speak now.');

// Create the stream.
var recognizeStream = speechToText.recognizeUsingWebSocket(params);

// Pipe in the audio.
var textStream = micInputStream.pipe(recognizeStream).setEncoding('utf8');

textStream.on('data', user_speech_text => console.log('Watson hears:', user_speech_text));
textStream.on('error', e => console.log(`error: ${e}`));
textStream.on('close', e => console.log(`close: ${e}`));
```

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52286957/how-to-get-the-microphone-streamed-directly-to-the-watson-speechtotext-service

Comment: I would put micInstance.start() after you connected all pipes.

Comment: Like here https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/blob/master/examples/speech_to_text_microphone_input/transcribe-mic-to-file.js

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev thanks, that github link's implementation is definitely a step in the right direction as I can now get back translations but it appears the wav stream (used in the github link) is recording my audio very slowly (5 seconds = 15-second wav file). It appears this slow recording is also being sent to Watson given the ughly translations I'm getting back. If I'm able to figure out what is causing this ill be sure to update my code for anyone curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Conclusion:** In the end, I am not entirely sure what was wrong with the code. I'm guessing it had something to do with the mic package. I ended up scrapping the package and using "Node-audiorecorder" instead for my audio stream https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-audiorecorder

**Note:** This module requires you to install SoX and it must be available in your $PATH. http://sox.sourceforge.net/

**Updated Code:** For anyone wondering what my final code looks like here you go. Also a *big shoutout to NikolayShmyrev* for trying to help me with my code!

Sorry for the heavy comments but for new projects I like to make sure I know what every line is doing.

```
    // Import module.
    var AudioRecorder = require('node-audiorecorder');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var SpeechToTextV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/speech-to-text/v1');


    /******************************************************************************
    * Configuring STT
    *******************************************************************************/
    var speechToText = new SpeechToTextV1({
        iam_apikey: '{your watson key here}',
        url: 'https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api'
    });

    var recognizeStream = speechToText.recognizeUsingWebSocket({
        content_type: 'audio/wav',
        interim_results: true
      });


    /******************************************************************************
    * Configuring the Recording
    *******************************************************************************/
    // Options is an optional parameter for the constructor call.
    // If an option is not given the default value, as seen below, will be used.
    const options = {
        program: 'rec',     // Which program to use, either `arecord`, `rec`, or `sox`.
        device: null,       // Recording device to use.

        bits: 16,           // Sample size. (only for `rec` and `sox`)
        channels: 2,        // Channel count.
        encoding: 'signed-integer',  // Encoding type. (only for `rec` and `sox`)
        rate: 48000,        // Sample rate.
        type: 'wav',        // Format type.

        // Following options only available when using `rec` or `sox`.
        silence: 6,         // Duration of silence in seconds before it stops recording.
        keepSilence: true   // Keep the silence in the recording.
      };

    const logger = console;

    /******************************************************************************
    * Create Streams
    *******************************************************************************/

    // Create an instance.
    let audioRecorder = new AudioRecorder(options, logger);

    //create timeout (so after 10 seconds it stops feel free to remove this)
    setTimeout(function() {
        audioRecorder.stop();
      }, 10000);

    // This line is for saving the file locally as well (Strongly encouraged for testing)
    const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream("test.wav", { encoding: 'binary' });

    // Start stream to Watson STT Remove .pipe(process.stdout) if you dont want translation printed to console
    audioRecorder.start().stream().pipe(recognizeStream).pipe(process.stdout);

    //Create another stream to save locally
    audioRecorder.stream().pipe(fileStream);

    //Finally pipe translation to transcription file
    recognizeStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./transcription.txt'));
```